# Having trouble setting up nuxt frontend with headless WordPress on Digital Ocean server

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, digital-ocean, nuxt.js

I'm trying to deploy a NuxtJS application that utilises the WordPress API. I have been trying for 2 days now to deploy these both on digital ocean but keep running into problems with sub domain issues. (This is my first real deployment)

My ideal situation would be to have 2 droplets, one for Nuxt and one for WordPress. My normal domain name would point to the Nuxt droplet and then I'd like to create a sub-domain of "api.domainname.co.uk" etc.

So far, i've made 2 droplets and pointed the normal domain to my Nuxt droplet and then attempted to create a A record for my subdomain to point at the IP address of my WordPress API droplet.

This is where the problems occur, when I now try visit the subdomain the connection keeps timing out and I can't seem to solve it.

What am I missing? Can I not host my subdomain on a separate droplet?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! The client was expecting this last week but have been delayed because of this :/

Any better way of deploying these 2 would also be welcome!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have two A records pointing to two different IP addresses.  The important point is that the subdomain's A record is part of the main domain's overall record (the zone record).

Meaning, you would have the following A records all within the record for domainname.co.uk:

```
@          IN   A   A.A.A.A       
www        IN   A   A.A.A.A       
api        IN   A   B.B.B.B
```

I don't know the specifics of how to do it within Digital Ocean's domain management, but this snippet is from zone records on nameservers I run and have a similar set up (subdomain on a different IP), so it is possible.